# "netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name program" syntax not working

Tags: windows-7, batch, windows-firewall, netsh

I'm trying to delete a Windows Firewall rule from command line using netsh. I'm trying with the below syntax; however, it is not working for me result wise.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule program="C\Program Files (x86)\utorrent\uTorrent.exe"
```

What is the correct syntax for this? I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found another powerfull solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
REG EXPORT "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules" "%TEMP%\RegBackup.reg" /y > NUL 2> NUL
TYPE "%TEMP%\RegBackup.reg" | FINDSTR /i /v torrent > "%TEMP%\RegBackupNew.reg"
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules" /f /va > NUL 2> NUL
REG IMPORT "%TEMP%\RegBackupNew.reg" 2> NUL
REG EXPORT "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules" "%TEMP%\RegBackup.reg" /y > NUL 2> NUL
TYPE "%TEMP%\RegBackup.reg" | FINDSTR /i /v torrent > "%TEMP%\RegBackupNew.reg"
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules" /f /va > NUL 2> NUL
REG IMPORT "%TEMP%\RegBackupNew.reg" 2> NUL
DEL /q "%TEMP%\RegBackup.reg" 2> NUL
DEL /q "%TEMP%\RegBackupNew.reg" 2> NUL
endlocal
```

Comment: I think your approach is too vast. Better were to export and filter with torrent and delete these keys, this ways leaving the majority of rules untouched.

Answer (score 14):

Don't use the "Program" parameter and value, use "Rule" name in the delete statement.

You can run `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule status=enabled name=all` or perhaps `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule status=enabled name=all | FIND /I "uTorrent"` to get a list of the rules that are enabled to help location the actual name of the rule.

Once this is determined, you can run `netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="<Rule Name>"` and plug the name of the rule in accordingly for it to remove that rule.

### Examples

**Create a rule with the name "IP Block"**

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IP Block" dir=in interface=any action=block remoteip=<IPaddress>/32
```

**Delete a rule with the name "IP Block"**

```
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="IP Block"
```

---

### Further Resources

- [NETSH](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html)
- [Using NETSH](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490939.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

None of your attempts contains a correct rule name.

If not supplying a distinct rule name use (according to [this help](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd734783(v=ws.10).aspx) )  `name=all` in combination with `program="C:\Program Files (x86)\utorrent\uTorrent.exe"`

```
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=all program="C:\Program Files (x86)\utorrent\uTorrent.exe"
```

> name = { all | *RuleName* }
>           Required.  You can specify one of the following values:
>
> - The rule name of the connection security rule you want deleted.
> - **all**. 
>     Specifies that all rules matching the criteria in the other
>             parameters are deleted.  If no other parameters are included
>             in the command then all connection security rules are deleted.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't able cast positive vote, but this delete multiple rules in one shot and is much more affidable. But this not delete the voice in ...................HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules. Why?

Comment: This works only on............HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules.................and not for.............HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules............................Not work on: ControlSet002............................Work on: ControlSet001

Comment: AFIK the currentcontrolset is mapped to only one of the controlsets. [Cite from this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291519/how-does-currentcontrolset-differ-from-controlset001-and-controlset002): `you only need to update the CurrentControlSet key... 
ControlSet001 and ControlSet002 are alternating backups of CurrentControlSet, you don't need to update them. The other key is kept as a backup for the Load Last Known Good Configuration boot option.`

Comment: How is update backup of controlset002?

Comment: How do I upgrade controlset002?*

Comment: Don't interfere with the windows mechanisms. The other controlset represents a former consistent state of your installation. It doesn't make sense to tamper with this consitency by loading this hive and manipulating it. **So don't update it**

Comment: Try at restart my sistem.

Comment: ControlSet002 has been updated automatically after the system restarts.
How can I avoid restarting windows to update it automatically?

Comment: I don't understand that request, you want to update but not on a reboot? You should completely ignore the `ControlSet00x` and **only** refer to the `CurrentControlSet`

Comment: currentcontrolset link only controlset001 and not controlset002. Delete uTorrent from firewall for controlSet002 happens only if I restart the system and only if utorrent is not present on ControlSet001. Is there a way to do it avoiding reboot the system?